# How to remove stuck containers if docker won't start? (due to stuck containers)

Tags: docker

I have some containers that appear to be stuck.

I have managed to get dockerd stopped.

Trying to do:

`systemctl start docker` just hangs.

I then tried:

`dockerd --debug`

And I get a ton of messages like `failed to exit within 10 seconds of signal 15` and `failed to exit within 10 seconds of kill`.

I don't want docker to try and do anything with these containers, I just want to nuke them. I can't even do `docker ps`, it just hangs.

So...I need docker to be running in order to remove these broken containers, but I can't start docker as long as these containers exist.

What do I do here? How do I remove containers if dockerd can't start?

Answer (score 2):

This is my goto sequence for getting Docker unstuck. In my experience this tends to happen now and then on a docker package upgrade if your containers are set to autostart and sometimes after OOM kills of containers.

Your system may differ in specifics.

```
killall containerd-shim
service containerd restart
rm -rf -- /var/run/docker/runtime-runc/moby/*
service docker restart
```

Answer (score 0):

You could mount the directory where the containers are and then delete the containers via "rm [filename]".