Misbehaving docker container process - box is unresponsive, and won't even reboot?
I have a Ampere ARM64 server, and I'm running a bunch of Docker containers on it (Frigate, Immich, InfluxDB, HomeAssistant.
However, I seem to have hit some issue with Frigate, which is pegging several of the cores at 100% - and has also made the box unresponsive:
https://github.com/blakeblackshear/frigate/discussions/15298
I'd like to see if there is some way to safely kill the misbehaving container, or if needed reboot the box. (Ideally I'd like to avoid just ripping the power cord out, and also avoid data loss/cleanup to other containers)
Trying a normal reboot seems to fail:
victorhooi@ampere-01 ~/homeassistant-docker> sudo shutdown -r now
[sudo] password for victorhooi:
Failed to set wall message, ignoring: Connection timed out
Call to Reboot failed: Connection timed out

I tried to stop the offending Frigate container - and that command basically hung there for several hours:
victorhooi@ampere-01 ~/frigate-docker> docker compose stop
WARN[0000] /home/victorhooi/frigate-docker/compose.yml: the attribute `version` is obsolete, it will be ignored, please remove it to avoid potential confusion
[+] Stopping 0/1
 ⠋ Container frigate  Stopping                                                                                                                                                                                                          32232.1s
nB

Docker commands don't seem to work well - docker stop, docker kill won't work (they just hang) - nor does say docker top, docker inspect etc.
Even trying to stop other docker containers on the box unrelated to Frigate seem to hang.
I even tried sending SIGKILL to some of the offending processes in that container - the command returned, but the processes stayed running.
Output from top:

But I tried htop, and that hung.
I do have some outputs from ps/pstree from the box:

https://gist.github.com/victorhooi/18926f95bb1adf3c31461691c63dadfb
https://gist.github.com/victorhooi/5335f6b86c10242c04bcae5ac7992ba6
https://gist.github.com/victorhooi/b3eb16c85e9077db66320f324f1cd2b4

From Googling it seems systemctl --force --force reboot might work - however, it could cause data loss etc - I'd like to try to understand a bit more before blindly running that.
Anyhow - my questions:

Containers aren't isolated like VMs - but what sort of things could cause them to hang the host machine like this?
Are there any investigations I could do on the container, it is current state? Or ephemeral data I should collect?
What's the safest way to kill the misbehaving container? Or if that's not possible, reboot the box?
Are there constraints that would help prevent this? (I suppose that's somewhat dependent on what the cause is. The weird thing is - I have plenty of cores left - Frigate is only pegging a few of them at 100% - so why is Docker as a whole unresponsive?)

Edit: Using systtemctl to try to get the status on the docker service also fails:
sudo systemctl status docker
[sudo] password for victorhooi:
Failed to get properties: Transport endpoint is not connected```


Do these steps help? https://serverfault.com/a/1079822/188737

How about just killing those frigate processes on the host? As far as I see, everything you're doing above requires some form of "collaboration" from Docker, which has obviously crashed badly. You have tried killing the offending processes, but only from within the container, which also requires a responsive Docker. As you mention, Docker is not a full-fledged VM, so every process running within a Docker container is also a host process, just with a restricted environment. Just try # kill -KILL <PID> as root on the host.
